# PfTrack: Exchange Projects to different machine?

Tags: tracking

Is it possible to take a project created in pftrack and transfer it to a different machine that also runs pftrack?

So far, the documentation I found via google was quite poor, I also couldn't find out whether pftrack is upward-/downward compatible.